# lambda with more than one effect

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have three different classes of some common interface `Bag`. Those are simple containers with some properties. I can add a bunch of stuff in them, e.g `int`s. For purposes of unit testing, I wanted to add a number of values to each and every one of those `Bag`s. So I used the following `IntConsumer`:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 300).forEach(new IntConsumer() {
    @Override
    public void accept(int value) {
        staticBag.add(value);
        shuffledBag.add(value);
        randomAccessBag.add(value);
        }
    });
```

My question is how that might be changeable to a lambda expression. `Intellij` is usually doing a pretty good job at changing those things automatically, but at this point it hasn't been showing me any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellij did it for me!  Here you go:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 300).forEach(value -> {
    staticBag.add(value);
    shuffledBag.add(value);
    randomAccessBag.add(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

add a utility method `accept(IntConsumer)` you can chain the functions with [IntConsumer.andThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntConsumer.html#andThen-java.util.function.IntConsumer-).

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 300).forEach(accept(staticBag::add)
                                     .andThen(shuffledBag::add)
                                     .andThen(randomAccessBag::add));

private IntConsumer accept(IntConsumer consumer) {
    return consumer;
}
```

OR add a utility method `accept(IntConsumer...)` to composing all consumers using [Stream.reduce(BinaryOperator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 300).forEach(accept(staticBag::add
                                     /**/, shuffledBag::add
                                     /**/, randomAccessBag::add));

private IntConsumer accept(IntConsumer... consumers) {
    IntConsumer nothing = (value) -> { };
    return Arrays.stream(consumers).reduce(IntConsumer::andThen).orElse(nothing);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 300)
  .peek(staticBag::add)
  .peek(shuffledBag::add)
  .forEach(randomAccessBag::add);
```

Comment: vote up first! you having mastered the stream api better than us. but peek method only support Consumer rather than any kind of Function Interfaces, could you give the common solutions for the Function Interfaces.

Comment: @holi-java the question only uses consumers. This won't work for functions, in that you can't do anything with a value returned from a function called by peek (although you can call a function, because a function is also a consumer)

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe what I described is wrong due to my bad english. I wish you can give us the best solution for any type of @FunctionInterface than ours.